# Soundcloud Widget - Event.PLAY not working

Tags: javascript, api, widget, soundcloud

I'm having problems with the SoundCloud Widget API.

For some reason the Event.PLAY is not working anymore...

```
var i, song, iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');

for (i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
    if (String.prototype.indexOf.call(iframes[i].src, '//w.soundcloud.com/player') > -1) 
    {           
        iframes[i].id = "sc_player_"+i;
        song = SC.Widget(iframes[i].id);                    
        song.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY, function(eventData){               
            song.getCurrentSound(function(sound) {
                console.log(sound.title);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The event handler not firing the first time the playback starts seems to be a bug on our side, we are looking into it.

Comment: The bug is fixed now, you should get PLAY events handled from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this, we are looking into why the PLAY event doesn't fire on first play right now.

**UPD**. The bug with `PLAY` event not firing on initial play was fixed now.

On a side note, there's a problem with your code: the functions you are creating (event handlers) inside of the loop will all reference the last iframe as `song`. You should either wrap the event handler creation in an IFFE passing the current `song` as a paramater:

```
for (i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
    if (src.indexOf('//w.soundcloud.com/player') > -1) {           
        iframes[i].id = "sc_player_"+i;
        song = SC.Widget(iframes[i].id);
        song.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY, (function (song) {
            return function(eventData){               
                song.getCurrentSound(function(sound) {
                    console.log(sound.title);
                });
            }
        }(song)));
    }
}
```

Or create a helper function that will return an event handler referencing the right `song`:

```
function createEventHandler (song) {
  // `song` will be “caught” in the closure
  return function (eventData) {
    song.getCurrentSound(function (sound) {
      console.log(sound.title);
    });
  }
}

for (i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
    if (src.indexOf('//w.soundcloud.com/player') > -1) {           
        iframes[i].id = "sc_player_"+i;
        song = SC.Widget(iframes[i].id);
        song.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY, createEventHandler(song));
    }
}
```